# Extending a class with a variable?

Tags: php

This works and is tested.
PHP Code:

```
$data_stats = json_decode($ret);
$projected_points = $data_stats->body->player_stats->42550689->FPTS
```

I just need to know how to do it using a variable. Something like this:
PHP Code:

```
$data_stats = json_decode($ret);
$projected_points = $data_stats->body->player_stats->$id->FPTS
```

How can I make $id work here?

Also is this called extending a class? I don't even know the correct terminology to describe my question.

Comment: No, this has nothing to with extending a class, this is just accessing a property of a class (in this case, `stdClass`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can access attributes using alternative syntax `$obj->player_stats->{$var}`

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a variable variable... something like:

$yourId = 42550689

Then, you do:

$projected_points = $data_stats->body->player_stats->$$yourId->FPTS

Check the docs for more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php